# Why this value is not the second root of the equation?

Tags: roots

$\sqrt{x+3}=x-2$

Why $\frac{5}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{21}}{2}$ is not root?

There is only one restriction: $\sqrt{x+3}$, but $\frac{5}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{21}}{2} > 0$.

$x^2-4x+4=x+3$,   $x^2-5x+1=0$,   $D=25-4=21>0$

$D>0$, =>, $x = \frac{ 5 \pm \sqrt{21} }{ 2 }$

Comment: "There is only one restriction"  No, there are two.  1) $\sqrt{x+3}$ is meaningful $\implies x \ge -3$.  And $\sqrt{x+3} \ge 0 \implies x+2 = \sqrt{x+3} \ge 0$.

Comment: Yes, this is my mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because $\left(\frac{5}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)-2$ is negative, so it cannot be the square root of something.

Answer (score 8):

There is actually a second restriction to your equation, which is "hidden":

Since $\sqrt{x+3} \geq 0$ you must also have $x-2 \geq 0$, which your root fails.

Note that the second root actually satisfies $\sqrt{x+3}=-(x-2)$.

Answer (score 3):

That is because the irrational equation:
$$\sqrt A=B\iff A=B^2\;\textbf{ and }\, B\ge 0,$$
i.e., in the present case, $\;x\ge 2$, whereas $\;\dfrac{5-\sqrt{21}}2<\dfrac12$.